# Swagger 3.0 array's null values

Tags: arrays, null, swagger, swagger-3.0

Is it possible to define an array that *can not* contain null?

I'm compiling it to Java with Open API 3.0

For example for this

```
A:
  type: array
  minItems: 1
  items:
    $ref: "#/components/schemas/B"
B: 
 type: string
 pattern: ^[a-z]+$
```

I consider [null] or ["abc",null] invalid

Thanks in advance